# Split in loop by regex Firstcapital letter word between each other

Tags: python-3.x, regex

i have some data

```
text = ['Hair dryer Babyliss 6713DE',
'Hair dryer Philips Drycare Advanced HP8232/00',
'Photoepilator Philips Lumea Prestige BRI953/00',
'Hair straighteners Philips MoistureProtect HP8374/00',
'Hair styling combs Babyliss AS83PE',
'Epilator Braun Silk-épil 9 Flex SES 9030',
'Hair dryer Babyliss 5513PE']
```

I need loop from each line and extract word between capitalized letters

expected result

```
Hair dryer, Babyliss, ,6713DE
Hair dryer, Philips, Drycare Advanced, HP8232/00
Photoepilator, Philips, Lumea Prestige, BRI953/00
Hair straighteners, Philips, MoistureProtect, HP8374/00
Hair styling combs, Babyliss, ,AS83PE
Epilator, Braun, Silk-épil 9 Flex, SES 9030
Hair dryer, Babyliss, ,5513PE
```

- So get array of {Type, Brand, Collection, Model}
- So (1st group) TYPE,will be From string begining until first capitalized letter
- So (2ndgroup) Brand, will be From first group until next first capitalized
  letter
- So (3rd group) Collection, will be between 2nd and 4rd groups
- So (4th group) Model, will be from last word with first capital letter until end

---

```
import re
[y for x in text for y in re.split(r' +', x)]]
```

Comment: [This one](https://regex101.com/r/dIW3XT/1) is close, but the last but one test case is not actually meeting your requirements as the model contains two words. Only one is captured now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex to capture all 4 named capture groups for given set of inputs:

```
^(?P<Type>\w+(?: +[a-z]\w*)*) +(?P<Brand>[A-Z]\w*) *(?P<Collection>[A-Z].*?|) +(?P<Model>(?:[A-Z]+ +)?[\dA-Z][\dA-Z/]*)$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/MRa2o0/1)

We have 4 named capture groups as per your requirements:

1. `P<Type>`: That captures from string beginning until first capitalized letter
2. `P<Brand>`: Starts with a capital letter and is a single word
3. `P<Collection>`: is an optional string that comes after `Brand` and stops before last group. Note that this group may be empty as well.
4. `P<Model>`: is the last group that start with a capital letter word or is a word that contains digits, uppercase letters and `/`

---

**Python Code:**

```
>>> import re
>>> text = ['Hair dryer Babyliss 6713DE',
... 'Hair dryer Philips Drycare Advanced HP8232/00',
... 'Photoepilator Philips Lumea Prestige BRI953/00',
... 'Hair straighteners Philips MoistureProtect HP8374/00',
... 'Hair styling combs Babyliss AS83PE',
... 'Epilator Braun Silk-épil 9 Flex SES 9030',
... 'Hair dryer Babyliss 5513PE']
>>> rx = re.compile(r'^(?P<Type>\w+(?: +[a-z]\w*)*) +(?P<Brand>[A-Z]\w*) *(?P<Collection>[A-Z].*?|) +(?P<Model>(?:[A-Z]+ +)?[\dA-Z][\dA-Z/]*)$')
>>> for i in text: print(rx.match(i).groupdict())
...
{'Type': 'Hair dryer', 'Brand': 'Babyliss', 'Collection': '', 'Model': '6713DE'}
{'Type': 'Hair dryer', 'Brand': 'Philips', 'Collection': 'Drycare Advanced', 'Model': 'HP8232/00'}
{'Type': 'Photoepilator', 'Brand': 'Philips', 'Collection': 'Lumea Prestige', 'Model': 'BRI953/00'}
{'Type': 'Hair straighteners', 'Brand': 'Philips', 'Collection': 'MoistureProtect', 'Model': 'HP8374/00'}
{'Type': 'Hair styling combs', 'Brand': 'Babyliss', 'Collection': '', 'Model': 'AS83PE'}
{'Type': 'Epilator', 'Brand': 'Braun', 'Collection': 'Silk-épil 9 Flex', 'Model': 'SES 9030'}
{'Type': 'Hair dryer', 'Brand': 'Babyliss', 'Collection': '', 'Model': '5513PE'}
```

Or using `findall`:

```
>>> for i in text: print( rx.findall(i)[0] )
...
('Hair dryer', 'Babyliss', '', '6713DE')
('Hair dryer', 'Philips', 'Drycare Advanced', 'HP8232/00')
('Photoepilator', 'Philips', 'Lumea Prestige', 'BRI953/00')
('Hair straighteners', 'Philips', 'MoistureProtect', 'HP8374/00')
('Hair styling combs', 'Babyliss', '', 'AS83PE')
('Epilator', 'Braun', 'Silk-épil 9 Flex', 'SES 9030')
('Hair dryer', 'Babyliss', '', '5513PE')
```